# Twitter Bootstrap Accordion - maintain state after postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have the Accordion dropdowns in an update panel. When a panel is opened and any Async postback performed the panel closes.

I can overcome this by running the following as part of the postback

```
Private Sub SectionOneKeepOpen()
    Try
        Dim SB As New StringBuilder
        SB.Append("$(document).ready(function(){")
        SB.AppendLine()
        SB.Append("$('#collapseOne').collapse('show');")
        SB.AppendLine()
        SB.Append("});")
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "ShowCollapse", SB.ToString, True)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim vError As New SendError
        vError.MailError(181, PageName, ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

It works, but it looks messy as the user gets a 'flash' as the panel closes and reopens and the scrollbar shoots back up and stays at where the panel was closed.

I have seen a number of possible solutions, like maintaining the state in a hidden field but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy solution - put Update Panels in each Accordion Panel. Spent so much time on desktop apps coming back to asp.net is like moving to another country :-)